# Interpreting a tomcat thread dump and diagnosing a deadlock

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, deadlock, thread-dump

I have the following thread dump (see below) and I am not sure whether I have a deadlock.

Can anyone please advise?

```
2013-03-22 08:52:59
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.7-b01 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68e8001000 nid=0x41bd waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-exec-10" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68840a2800 nid=0x41b5 in Object.wait() [0x00007f690cc57000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007e8fc4650> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1115)
    - locked <0x00000007e8fc4650> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.connection.InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(InjectedDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1395)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:273)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$before$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at com.bignibou.service.MemberServiceImpl.retrieveCurrentMember(MemberServiceImpl.java:15)
    at com.bignibou.controller.MessageController.getMessages(MessageController.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:816)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    - locked <0x00000007d9c6f578> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000007d79a5758> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)

"http-bio-8080-exec-9" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68c8426000 nid=0x41b4 waiting on condition [0x00007f690cd5b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007f7241b98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-exec-8" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68b800c000 nid=0x41b3 waiting on condition [0x00007f690cf5e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007f7241b98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-exec-7" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68b800a000 nid=0x41b2 waiting on condition [0x00007f690d05f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007f7241b98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-exec-6" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68b8008000 nid=0x41b1 waiting on condition [0x00007f690d65a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007f7241b98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-exec-5" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68b8006800 nid=0x41b0 waiting on condition [0x00007f690d75b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007f7241b98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-exec-4" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68b8005000 nid=0x41af waiting on condition [0x00007f690d85c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007f7241b98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-exec-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68b8004000 nid=0x41ae waiting on condition [0x00007f690db5f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007f7241b98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-exec-2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68b000e000 nid=0x41ab waiting on condition [0x00007f690d95d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007f7241b98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"ajp-bio-8009-AsyncTimeout" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f69184a5000 nid=0x41aa waiting on condition [0x00007f690d160000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"ajp-bio-8009-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f69184a3000 nid=0x41a9 runnable [0x00007f690d261000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:216)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-exec-1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68b8002000 nid=0x41a8 waiting on condition [0x00007f690d362000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007f7241b98> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.take(TaskQueue.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-AsyncTimeout" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f69184a1800 nid=0x41a7 waiting on condition [0x00007f690d463000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$AsyncTimeout.run(JIoEndpoint.java:148)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"http-bio-8080-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f691849f800 nid=0x41a6 runnable [0x00007f690e2db000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Acceptor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:216)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f691875c800 nid=0x41a5 waiting on condition [0x00007f690e3dc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1508)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Timer-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f68c4a93800 nid=0x41a4 in Object.wait() [0x00007f690da5e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007f7abdda0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:552)
    - locked <0x00000007f7abdda0> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"GC Daemon" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f691866b000 nid=0x419e in Object.wait() [0x00007f690eb3c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007836c8508> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)
    at sun.misc.GC$Daemon.run(GC.java:117)
    - locked <0x00000007836c8508> (a sun.misc.GC$LatencyLock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Service Thread" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f69180f0800 nid=0x419b runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f69180ee800 nid=0x419a waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f69180eb800 nid=0x4199 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f69180e9000 nid=0x4198 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f691809c000 nid=0x4197 in Object.wait() [0x00007f690fefd000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000785b731f8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x0000000785b731f8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:177)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f691809a000 nid=0x4196 in Object.wait() [0x00007f690fffe000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000785b72da8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x0000000785b72da8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"main" prio=10 tid=0x00007f6918009000 nid=0x4190 runnable [0x00007f6920b89000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:398)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:522)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:452)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:766)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:712)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f6918092800 nid=0x4195 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f6918017000 nid=0x4191 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f6918019000 nid=0x4192 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f691801a800 nid=0x4193 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x00007f691801c800 nid=0x4194 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f69180fb000 nid=0x419c waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 439
```

I have run jstack on the process and it has not detected any deadlock. However, Tomcat hangs  indefinitely when I run my webapp and the following code is executed 9 times:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getMessages", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public DeferredResult<List<Message>> getMessages(@RequestParam final Long senderId) {
        final Long recipientId = memberService.retrieveCurrentMember().getId();
        final String messageRequestKey = new StringBuilder().append(senderId).append(":").append(recipientId).toString();
        final DeferredResult<List<Message>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<List<Message>>(null, Collections.emptyList());
        messageRequests.put(messageRequestKey, deferredResult);

        deferredResult.onCompletion(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                messageRequests.remove(messageRequestKey);
            }
        });

        List<Message> unReadMessages = messageService.findUnreadMessages(senderId, recipientId);
        if (!unReadMessages.isEmpty()) {
            deferredResult.setResult(unReadMessages);
        }
        return deferredResult;
    }
```

If it isn't a deadlock, what else can it be?

Comment: Are you sure the messageRequests.remove(messageRequestKey); call is finishing?

Comment: Hi CodeChimp! Yes I am indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a connection leak and your database connection pool has run out of connections. Turn on abandoned connection logging to find the leak.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark! Can you please tell me what specific lines in the thread dump helped you figured that out?

Comment: The only thread doing anything is blocked at GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(). That call only blocks for anything more than a few milliseconds if the pool is empty. Since no other threads are doing anything that might be using a DB connection, the obvious explanation for an empty pool is a connection leak.

Comment: One more question: you say: "the only thread doing anything". How can you tell it is the only one? How about this one for instance: `http-bio-8080-exec-9`?

Comment: How can I tell? Experience (but that won't help you). You can look at the source code for the relevant bits of the Tomcat source code to see what is happening. That thread is sat in the executor pool waiting to be given something to do.

Comment: @MarkThomas could you explain in details what do you mean by 'Turn on abandoned connection' ?

Comment: It is a feature of the connection pool that identifies code that borrows a connection from the pool but never returns it.