# Tomcat hangs in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, threadpool, connection-pooling

I am working in a web application which using **Spring boot,SQL server activiti,websocket and angularJS**.

Sometimes, this application UI hangs ( not always ). I suspect this is because of connection pooling. This application is using **default datasource properties** from Spring Boot. There is **no connection pool library** used until now.

**Questions:**

I suspect **thread is waiting** for DB connection, so...

1) Increasing Maximum active connections will solve this problem?

2) Using connection pools libraries will solve this problem?

I attached **thread dump** below....

```
    MessageBrokerSockJS-3 prio=10 tid=0x00007f8c1c3d1800 nid=0xebd in  Object.wait() [0x00007f8c609c2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007095cd788> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1118)
    - locked <0x00000007095cd788> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:204)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.AbstractQuery.list(AbstractQuery.java:138)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.db.dao.ActivitiHelper.getTasksByTaskLocalVar(ActivitiHelper.java:305)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.db.dao.ActivitiHelper$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$86c44488.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.db.dao.ActivitiHelper$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$71f2d0fd.getTasksByTaskLocalVar(<generated>)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.manager.ActivitiManager.getTasksByTaskLocalVar(ActivitiManager.java:861)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.manager.ActivitiManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f69deb1c.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.manager.ActivitiManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$31946c7.getTasksByTaskLocalVar(<generated>)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.manager.AlfrescoManager.unlockTaskForClosedDocument(AlfrescoManager.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"MessageBrokerSockJS-2" prio=10 tid=0x00007f8c1e484000 nid=0xebc waiting on condition [0x00007f8c60ac4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000007041a9590> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:186)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2043)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1085)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:807)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"MessageBrokerSockJS-1" prio=10 tid=0x00007f8c1c9c6000 nid=0xeb6 in Object.wait() [0x00007f8c60bc4000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007095d02d8> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1118)
    - locked <0x00000007095d02d8> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:391)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:549)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.db.dao.ChaserDao.clearOldChasers(ChaserDao.java:111)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.db.dao.ChaserDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fa074cd3.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.db.dao.ChaserDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$48b6e5eb.clearOldChasers(<generated>)
    at com.rbccm.workflow.sendchaser.SendChaser.checkChasers(SendChaser.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"container-0" prio=10 tid=0x00007f8c1c930000 nid=0xeb5 waiting on condition [0x00007f8c60cc6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:407)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer$1.run(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:146)

"ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f8c149fa000 nid=0xeb4 waiting on condition [0x00007f8c60dc7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565533/interpreting-a-tomcat-thread-dump-and-diagnosing-a-deadlock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Kedar Parikh, the link provided by you was very useful to read the thread dump and find the root cause of this problem.

From the stack trace in this question, below line indicates, this thread is waiting to borrow(get) a database connection from the pool.

```
org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1118)
```

In this case, Tomcat hangs because **some threads were waiting for database connection**.

As I answered my own (another) question, I was able to monitor my database connection pool. 
By using this monitor/logging, I found the connection leak in my application.

For more details on, How to monitor/log database connection pool, refer 
[How to Debug / Log Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool's connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36587023/how-to-debug-log-tomcat-jdbc-connection-pools-connections)