# The org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx not showing up on JConsole

Tags: jdbc, jmx, tomcat8, jconsole, connection-pool

I've research how to monitor connection pool on Tomcat server. After research I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002625/8402916).

Per his answer, I choose option 2 - Monitoring using JMX (Java Management Extensions). I try to set up JMX on Tomcat server and finally, I can remote to monitor Memory usage, CPU usage, Thread pool and Loaded classes.

However, I couldn't monitor the connection pool because the `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx` in the MBeans tab is missing. (I should be like this [expected picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SglUS.png) but I got this [actual picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgSmA.png))

So, is there any way to montitor connection pool by using JConsole or could anyone can help answer me why `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx` doesn't show on JConsole?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx didn't show in JConsole is right now we didn't use JDBC anymore. Sorry for my misunderstanding.

I can monitor numActive, numIdle of the connection pool by using JConsole (it's appear in MBean section and the path is Tomcat/Datasource/localhost/javax.sql.DataSource/name-of-datasource/Attributes).

However, the chart of numActive and numIdle does not maintain historical data.

After researching, I found this http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmx-monitoring-using-collectd-influxdb-grafana/ it said we have to use another plug-in to collect data and visualize it. So, I try to setup these tools and finally it works!

Thanks.